# Play framework interactive console - Access class which has DI

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, playframework-2.6

Im using Play 2.6.

I use `sbt console` to get into the interactive console.

Im using this link to bootstrap the app
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayConsole#launch-the-interactive-console

Ive a typical model which is as below

```
@Singleton

class UserRepository @Inject() (@NamedDatabase("mysql") dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
```

How do I get access to the singleton instance of UserRepository inside the REPL ?

Answer (score 1):

Im using this link to bootstrap the app https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayConsole#launch-the-interactive-console

This will give you access to the app

```
import play.api._
val env = Environment(new java.io.File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Dev)
val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(env)
val loader = ApplicationLoader(context)
val app = loader.load(context)
Play.start(app)

// Now to load my classwith all the dependencies injected and ready to use
val c = Class.forName("user.UserRepository")
val repo = app.injector.instanceOf(c).asInstanceOf[user.UserRepository]
repo.list
```